# Is a puffy freezer bag a sign of spoilage?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, frozen, thawing

Recently I had bought some chicken and put it in the freezer to keep it because it wasn't going to be used right away.

That was about a week ago maybe two, last night I took some of the chicken out and put it in the fridge to thaw overnight and I didn't notice anything strange. But tonight when I took it out to cook I noticed the bag was slightly puffy, not like ballooned out or anything just puffy. If I press on it I can feel that there's air in there. I wanted to know if that's a sign of spoilage and if the chicken is still safe to use?

Comment: Pv=nrt , so some expansion is going to happen to a sealed bag but it's hard to say how much one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the bag was cold from the freezer, when you took it out the air inside it expanded slightly when it warmed to match the refrigerator or ambient temperature.

The expansion from the air and contents may explain some moderate puffiness.